# Understanding: Boundaries of the sets are level contours as drawn on topographic maps

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For convex function $c:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, the boundaries of the sets $S_t=\{x:c(x)\le t,x\in \mathbb{R^2}\},~t\in\mathbb{R}$ are level contours such as are drawn on topographic maps. Such a map is shown below.

[image]

I don't really understand this statement or the map. Some basic explanation or intuition on it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a bit wrong to me,

You understand that a convex function is one such that any straight line between two points on its graph goes entirely above the graph and intersects it only in those two points

Now to get level contours of the map one should instead consider the set $S_t = \{\,\, p = (x,\, y,\, z)\,\, st: c(x,\,y)=t\,\}$

Now is it clear to you that this set considers the countour subset of the functions graph along which $c$ has constant value: $t$, i.e it is like taking out a level curve which marks the functions graph reaching a certain height t exactly at/along it.

Comment: Oh makes sense, thank you! Also, $S_t$ they mentioned represents both the points on the boundary and the inside the ellipse while the contours are representative of the boundary points. Is that why you said "Seems a bit wrong to me"

Comment: Yea I suppose I misunderstood a bit and that the original definition was correct

Comment: but anyways you could just drop z and get the level curves on like a flat map which would be a good way of representing the function on a flat paper or smt, but you would need a reference height and a reference equidistant